# Finding the derivative of this function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was wondering if you could give me some help on solving this problem. I feel like this problem requires some knowledge of trigonometric identities, and I am a bit rusty on my trigonometry.
Here it is..

$f(x) = 3\sin x \cos x$

Find $f'(x)$.

After using the product rule, I've gotten $3\sin x\cos x+3\times\cos^2x-3\times\sin^2x$. So far, is that correct?

Comment: You might want to consider using the product rule of differentiation. $$f(x) = u(x)v(x)w(x) \implies f'(x) = u'(x)v(x)w(x) + u(x)v'(x)w(x) + u(x)v(x)w'(x)$$

Comment: No trig identities are necessary, but you could use $2\sin{x} \cos{x} = \sin{2x}$ to make the answer simpler.

Comment: After using the product rule, I've gotten
3sinxcosx+3xcos^2x-3xsin^2x

So far, is that correct?

Comment: I got the answer right, so thank you both so much. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here we need to use the product rule.

So we have that:

$$f(x) = 3x\sin x\cos x = \frac{3}{2}x\sin 2x$$

Now, we have:

$$f'(x) = \frac{3}{2}\sin 2x + 3x\cos 2x$$